# Comboboxes and changing items with selections

Tags: combobox

I am trying to figure out how to set up my code so that when an option is selected in a combo box, it changes the text of a label as well. From what I understand it involves something called an item listener but we did not discuss anything about that in class. We recently went over inheritance and interfaces but I do not see how that would apply here.

Answer (score 0):

```
//this event is fired whenever user selects or change a item from combobox

private void comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //do whatever you want to do in this
}

 for android do this

  spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        // your code here
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        // your code here
    }

});
```

Comment: Does this work in java, specifically netbeans? It gives me a red underline for object and EventArgs.